# Assign column header to other data frame based on condition in python

Tags: python, pandas

df1:

```
string            country
i live in NY
chicago is best
delhi is xyz
```

df2:

```
usa      india  china  france
NY       Delhi  xyz    paris
Chicago
SF
```

Output:
df1:

```
string            country
i live in NY      usa
chicago is best   usa
delhi is xyz      india
```

Basically, need to assign column header to another dataframe if that df contains substring defined in that column. 

 P.S. df2 contains so many columns. Cannot list one by one.

Comment: Have you tried named entity recognition in NLTK https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-named-entity-recognition-using-spacy-7140ebbb3718

Comment: My actual need is customized. NLTK wont be any help.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I would create a dictionary which allows a quick lookup of a country from a given city. Then you can go through each word and check whether it is inside the dictionary.

Depending on how complex your strings are, you should check some edge cases by yourself, e.g. strings containing punctuation marks or multiple cities.

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'usa': ['ny', 'chicago'],
    'india': ['delhi', 'mumbay'],
    'china': ['bejing', 'shanghai'],
    'france': ['paris', 'toulouse']
})
city_country = {
    city: country 
    for country, cities in df2.to_dict(orient='list').items() 
    for city in cities
}

def get_country_for_string(string):
    for word in string.split():
        if word.lower() in city_country:
            return city_country[word.lower()]
    return None

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['strings'] = ['i live in NY', 'chicago is best', 'delhi is xyz']
df1['country'] = list(map(get_country_for_string, df1['strings']))
print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
           strings country
0     i live in NY     usa
1  chicago is best     usa
2     delhi is xyz   india
```